# jQuery scrollTop Trouble

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting `scrollTop` to work on a search page I'm working on. Here's my code:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("Search") > -1) {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#ditto_results").offset().top}, 2500);
});
```

I need to check the URL for the string "Search" to see if a search has been completed, and if so, scroll the page to the `#ditto_results div`. When I perform a search nothing happens though.

If I replace the first line with a click event it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably not the issue but indexOf() is a case sensitive method, so is your Search actually search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably immediately executing this code wherever it's positioned within your document... You should use document ready event instead which will execute immediately after document is ready so all elements are loaded (not necessarily their content ie. images) including your `#ditto_results` `div` element:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Search") > -1) {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#ditto_results").offset().top}, 2500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the document ready event but it's still not acting like it's supposed to.

Comment: did you try debugging it with Firebug to see whether that particular div is present at time of execution?